# Manual for Ubuntu's break command

Tags: ubuntu, bash

**Where is the manual for Ubuntu's break -command?**

I run

```
~ master $ man break
No manual entry for break
~ master $ break
break: not in while, until, select, or repeat loop
~ master $
```

Without manual it is difficult to understand the purpose of the command.
It may be linked to the for -loops of the C -codes of the kernel.
I do not believe that it is the break for Bash.

Comment: break is a bash builtin, not a command.  Type `help break` at the prompt.

Comment: Also try `type -a break` at the prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Bash:

```
$ help break
break: break [n]
    Exit for, while, or until loops.

    Exit a FOR, WHILE or UNTIL loop.  If N is specified, break N enclosing
    loops.

    Exit Status:
    The exit status is 0 unless N is not greater than or equal to 1.
```

The error message you are seeing is issued by Bash. What is the context in which you are trying to understand "break"?

In C, `break` is a keyword. See [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Control#Loops) for more information. In part, it says:

> A break statement will immediately exit the enclosing loop.

Comment: An answer that addresses the question!  Yeah!

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, what you are after is:

```
man bash
```

alternatively you can also issue:

```
man bash | grep -C5 "break [n]"
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I missed your note about not being the bash break. :-| However I can't reproduce the error message you get. I get instead:

```
bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

What version of ubuntu do you use? What version of bash? Mine is version 4.0.33(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)... I am asking just in case the two different messages are both from bash but from different versions...

What does

```
which break
```

output to you? If it is a standalone program you will get the directory where the executable is located and thus probably be able to understand what installation is part of. If it is a bash (ot other shell) command it will silently fail (no output).

Comment: I use Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: I use Ubuntu 9.10 too (64 bit) so it does look like it is another program, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A googling came up with [this](http://etics-01.cnaf.infn.it/rundir/condor_etics-01.cnaf.infn.it_1176374857_661/userdir/common/zsh-4.2.6/Src/builtin.c) link, suggesting that the `break` command you've come across is indeed not from `bash`; it's from `zsh`. Hence you should be able to get the correct manual by issuing `man zshbuiltins`.

Comment: In case you are right the man command to issue would however be `man zshbuiltins` (see this: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zsh-4.3.4/)

Answer (score 0):

i also have an ubuntu 9.10 installation. if if issue:

```
media@faun:~$ break
-bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
media@faun:~$
```

you see that this output definitely comes from bash. if you issue

```
media@faun:~$ su -
media@faun:~$ find / -name "break"
```

and

```
media@faun:~$ which break
media@faun:~$ type break
```

you see that there is no other binary and that break is bash builtin. the manual to break is in the manual for bash.

```
media@faun:~$ man bash
```

the error message you get is indeed from using the builtin break in a situation it doesn't work. you can try it like this:

```
media@faun:~$ for i in 0 1
> do
> echo $i
> done
0
1
media@faun:~$
```